# Fixed elements flicker iOS?

Tags: jquery, ios, css

I'm having a problem on iOS where a jQuery sticky menu flickers on iOS. I do not experience the problem on desktop or Android.

I researched this thoroughly and all answers have suggested to use a transform rule. I have so far tried adding:

```
.sticky-nav {transform: translateZ(0);}
```

as well as:

```
.sticky-nav {transform: translate3d(0,0,0);}
```

I am applying this to the main nav class. It still won't work. Is it because it is a device issue?

Comment: What browser on iOS? You might need to add vendor prefixes (`-webkit-`) to the `transform` property

Comment: My build system adds them automatically. And this occurs on all browsers (chrome, safari, firefox etc.) on all iOS devices.

Comment: What other CSS is applied to the `.sticky-nav`? Do you have a live demo or jsFiddle example for us to inspect? Have you tried adding `backface-visibility: hidden` and `transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0)`?

Comment: the other css is: "border: none;
  @include border-radius(0px);
  margin-bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);" I did try the backface-visibility. I have not however tried perspective (1px)

Comment: Ok I just tried for both to no avail. I have seen a lot of complaints about iOS 9.3.1 in terms of general use. I'm not so sure there is much to be done about it.